# C# best practices

Tags: c#, .net, design-patterns

I've got an issue similar to the theoretical situation below and am looking to follow the industry best practice.

Use case:
A user may tip the staff based on a flat amount or a percentage of services rendered.

UI:
The user would be given a dropdown asking percent or $ and a value. The user would then be given a textbox to enter an amount.

Question:
Underneath the hood, would you have a two separate values - one for percent and one for dollars, or would you just have one value whose meaning is determined by the value of an enum? (Or would you do something else?)

Comment: Asking for an "industry best practice" here is absurd. It all depends on *your requirements*.

Answer (score 2):

If you're talking about the *ViewModel*, I'd choose one value and an enum, because that directly corresponds to your view (a text field and a dropdown).

In this case, I believe the same structure makes sense for the persistence / domain model layer, because you'll have to use a different logic based on the enum. However, I'd also store the final amount that was calculated. This is redundant, but for any kind of billing/accounting system, it's helpful to have immutable values (which are not subject to interpretation) **and** a 'history' of how that value was calculated.

However, I don't see much of a reusable pattern in this. It's up to a number of details of the environment; depending on your UI library a different approach might be better.

Answer (score 1):

You could create a value type to represent what the user entered:

This could also be a class with getters and setters, so that data-binding is possible.

```
struct ServicesRenderedValue
{
    public readonly decimal Value;
    public readonly Unit Unit;
}

enum Unit
{
    Percentage,
    Dollars,
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with separate values. It doesn't make sense to store a value with context-sensitive meaning and might lead to bugs further down the line if the relationship between value and enum is not properly observed.

Answer (score 0):

I'd go with one value whose meaning is determined by the combo selection. You don't need two values if you're using only one of them.

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to have an interface Tip, with two classes implementing it: PercentageTip (with a percentage) and AbsoluteTip (with a dollar value). The Tip interface for example defines a property DollarAmount, so that you know how much you should take out of your wallet.

Answer (score 0):

For what it's worth, I can't see any point in complicating it with the level of detail of storing what method was used to calculate the tip.  I'd just store the value that is calculated.  The only value you care about is likely to be "How much of the payment should go to tips?" so just store the financial amount.

My reasoning is that if, for some reason, the total without tip changes, that should not affect the amount that was taken from the customer as a tip.